Question on using the elbow method for calculating ideal number of clusters for k means cluster analysis
Newb to cluster analysis here. I have a group of 35 subjects. For all of the subjects I have data for different measures of IQ (verbal, math, etc) and different biomarkers. There are 6 IQ measures in total and 4 biomarkers in total (let's call them biomarkers w, x, y, and z). I'm trying to run k means cluster analysis to see if there are meaningful subgroups of subjects within the group with distinguishable features (i.e., certain combinations of one or more IQ measures and biomarkers) - for example, maybe I'll find a subgroup of 7 subjects with low verbal IQ, low math IQ, high levels of biomarker x, and low levels of biomarker z, and perhaps I'll find another subgroup of 10 subjects with high reading IQ, low levels of biomarker w, and low levels of biomarker x. I'm trying to determine the ideal number of clusters to use for the analysis. To do this I'm using the elbow method, whereby I graph the within-cluster sum of squares (i.e., the sum of the squared distance of every point to its corresponding cluster center) as a function of the number of clusters (k). I did this for k = 2-20. See the graph below. Unfortunately it doesn't really seem obvious where the elbow is, if there is any at all - I would continue to add to the graph for values of k > 20 but it seems pretty unlikely that there will actually be that many clusters here. Do ya'll see an elbow point in the graph? Any thoughts on what to do? Any help is appreciated.


Clustering very quickly falls prey to the curse of dimensionality (e.g., Klawonn et al., 2015, https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-48577-4_2). If I understand you correctly, you have no less than 10 dimensions, and only 35 data points. In a situation like this, anything you "find" will likely be just noise. What is your scientific question? To be honest, 35 data points is very little for any analysis. Ideally, you should generate hypotheses on a subset of your data and then evaluate them on a test sample, and you absolutely don't have enough data for that.

I agree with @StephanKolassa .. I'd add that the elbow method is just one way of doing this. I prefer looking at solutions with various numbers of clusters and thinking about what I find in a more subjective way: Does this solution tell me something interesting? But with N = 35 I'd be very cautious about any result from any cluster analysis method. How hard is it for you to get more data?

@StephanKolassa Thanks for your reply. In a previous study I found some interesting correlations between some of the biomarkers and some of the IQ measures, and I have reason to believe that there are certain subgroups of the participants that are driving the correlations. And so that's why I wanted to do cluster analysis... to identify the subgroups if they are there. If you have any other suggestions about ways to get at this, please let me know. Thanks.

@PeterFlom Thanks for your reply. The only other data I have is from a control group of n = 35 that was used to compare to the n=35 I mentioned in a previous study. But I'm only interested in the n=35 I mentioned for the cluster analysis; so the control group can't be included. Unfortunately I can't get any more data :(
